# How do I create a save/unsave toggle button with Angular and two POST requests?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a save/unsave link like the one you'll find on a Reddit page.

**Desired behavior**

Objects (stories) are listed.
Each object contains a link called "save" if the object isn't already saved, and "unsave" if the object is already saved. Basically, it's a typical "favorite" button, except the indicator is a word, not a heart icon or anything of that sort.
When a user clicks "save," the word "save" changes into "unsave" and vise-versa.

**What I have so far**

```
var app = angular.module('feed', ['angularMoment'])

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}])


.factory('Stories',function($http, moment){
  return {
    load: function(){
      return $http.get('axeapi/stories/popular/').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data.results;
            // console.log(data);
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Poop");
        });
    }, // end load

    save: function(story) {
        var fav_link = "story/" + story + "/favorite/";
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

        // alert(csrftoken);
        $http.post(fav_link, {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken }).
              success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("saved");
                story.saved = true;
              }).
              error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
              });

        story.saved = true;
    } // end save

    unsave: function(story) { 
      // http POST; 'unfavorite' requst
      // return story.saved = false;
    }
  }
})

.controller("PostController", function($scope, moment, Stories) {
    $scope.saved_status = "save";
    $scope.foo = {
      bar: 'world'
    };

    Stories.load().then(function(stories){
      console.log(stories)
      $scope.stories = stories.data.results;
    });

    $scope.saveStory = function(story){
      Stories.save(story);
      $scope.saved_status = "unsave"
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="PostController">
    <div class="row row-centered" data-ng-repeat="story in stories">
        <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
            <div class="post-title"><h4><a href="/story/{{ story.id }}/">{{story.title}}</a></h4></div>

            <a class="post-links save-story" data-story-id="{{ story.id }}" ng-click="saveStory(story.id)">{{ saved_status }}</a>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current behavior**

When I click "save," all of the 'saves' turn into "unsave."
Whenever I click "save," I don't quite know how to switch the action to a call to the `unsave` written in a factory I started writing.

Comment: I have a suspicion, but could you post controller code as well first, seeing as that's where your click function is presumably handled.

Comment: @azium The controller is inside of the code above (the javascript you see).

Comment: Oh sorry invisible scroll bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each story needs its own `saved_status`. Right now you have one per controller, not one per story. Change it to this, you should be fine:

**UPDATE**
Just noticed you were sending only the `id` of the post in your click. Send the whole object, this will be easier to work with.

```
<!-- html -->
<div data-ng-repeat="story in stories">
  <a ng-click="saveStory(story)">{{ story.saved_status }}</a>
</div>
```

```
.controller('PostController', function($scope, moment, Stories) {
  Stories.load().then(function(stories){
    $scope.stories = stories.data.results
    // this can be done differently, but as an example this is what you need
    angular.forEach($scope.stories, function (story) {
      story.saved_status = story.saved // if saved, say unsave and vice versa
        ? 'Unsave'
        : 'Save'
    })
  })

  $scope.saveStory = function(story) {
    var savedStatus = story.saved_status
    // if the button said 'Save', call Stories.save(), otherwise do opposite
    if (savedStatus === 'Save') {
      Stories.save(story.id) // send id
      story.saved_status = 'Unsave'
    }
    else {
      Stories.unsave(story.id) // send id
      story.saved_status = 'Save'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is good, but does this account for the save/unsave POST requests? Where would I include those in this logic?

Comment: You have two options for that. You can either use [latency compensation](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation) and update the client, then wait for the post request to return to see if there was an error and re-update the client, or you can handle switching the save / unsave text after your post call has returned. Make sense?

Comment: Not really. I just need to know where to make the POST and switch. haha, I'm new to this. The theory would be nice, but I'm sorta pressed for time.

Comment: If it helps, I don't think you need to change anything in the logic. You can access the `saved_status` of the story you just clicked to determine whether you need to send a save POST, or an unsave POST.

Comment: haha, No prob. So, with your code, now the text doesn't change and only the 'unsave' POST request is sent upon click. There are no errors (the requests return 200s), so I'm not quite sure if it's working. Here's the new, full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/B2f1MMsMiobExp5fgaQE?p=catalogue

Comment: Ah I see, you are sending the `id` of the post when you click. Send the whole story and you can pass the `id` in POST, while also changing the text. Updated answer again